# Manually schedule a job in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, scheduled-tasks, job-scheduling

I want to create a schedule to manipulate some data on server. and i have store procedure which have some sql query. Now i want to exec this sp every day.

For that i have created job, schedule using sp_add_job, sp_add_schedule etc.. now all this needs to run on my clients server.

Now problem is that, I cant run these queries in client server as I don't have "sa" (admin) login. So is there any alternate way to run this query?

And also i cant create job from SQ L Server Agent in Object Explorer as I don't have rights to do it.

So Is there any way to create job on server?

Comment: Have you thought about setting up a windows scheduled task instead? though I suspect that this will require similar rights.

Comment: No i have to not tried for windows scheduled task. but let me try to do this. yes you are right in that also needs same rights issue and client machine is host on other server. so it is not possible to create windows scheduled task.

Answer (score 0):

You can do try two solutions:

Use a bat file that executes sqlcmd using the Windows built in scheduler.

or

You can create an SSIS project that executes a sql step task and assign the proc to the SQL task.. Once again once you can use Windows scheduler to execute the SSIS package.

Either one of these would take you around 1-2 hours to learn how to use the tools (if you have never done it before) and set up and use them.